# Is it common/normal for tf.keras.model.predict() to generate a value outside of the data range?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Is it normal for `tf.keras.model.predict()` to generate a value outside of the given data range?

I'm getting a negative value from `model.predict()`.  The data from the target prediction column used in the model consisted of only 1 or 0.  I would have expected `model.predict()` to generate a value between 0 and 1.

When I put new similar data into `model.predict()` to attempt to get a classification, I often get back a value less than 0 or greater than 1. Should I take this to mean that all values greater than 0.5 are more likely to be 1 and the higher the value more likely it is to be 1?

Here is my code:

```py
    epoch_count = 1    
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      feature_layer,
      layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
      layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
      layers.Dense(1)
    ])
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    model.fit(train_ds,
              validation_data=val_ds,
              epochs=epoch_count)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are being confused because your model actually outputs logits, not probabilities (in the `[0, 1]` range).

Since you are using `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)` as the loss, you have configured it to accept logits (this is what `from_logits=True` does), meaning that inside the loss a `sigmoid` activation is being applied.

After training, if you want to have outputs in the `[0, 1]` range, you should apply a `sigmoid` activation. You can do it like this:

```
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

After this, once you `predict` on the model, you will get `[0, 1]` values.

Comment: this didn't seem to work for me.  Getting an error AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @Kven Sure, it should be add, not append

Comment: I ended up using model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

Comment: @Kven An additional layer or just a modification of the last Dense layer?

Comment: as an additional layer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can happen when you have a shift in your data. I.e. if your data inputs have a distribution shift you can often get values pushed in different directions. If you want to make sure that you can get probabilities out instead of values, add a softmax function. This will bound your outputs between 0 and 1.

```
keras.activations.softmax(x, axis=-1)
```

Comment: Yes, after training.